# A bridge (game) related question

Tags: macros, cards

With the help of egreg, my bridge-related macros have come a long way. The following MWE:

```
%********************************************************************************
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in,paperheight=9in, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{libertine}
%********************************************************************************


%********************************************************************************
% Use MnSymbol suit symbols

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolCards}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.1] MnSymbolC5
   <6-7>  s*[1.1] MnSymbolC6
   <7-8>  s*[1.1] MnSymbolC7
   <8-9>  s*[1.1] MnSymbolC8
   <9-10> s*[1.1] MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> s*[1.1] MnSymbolC10
  <12->   s*[1.1] MnSymbolC12}{}

\newcommand{\mndiamond}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A2}}}
\newcommand{\mnheart}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A3}}}
\newcommand{\mnspade}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A4}}}
\newcommand{\mnclub}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A5}}}
%********************************************************************************


%********************************************************************************
% BRIDGE HAND
% macros to produce horizontal and vertical bridge hand

%Defines "hair space" to be used after suit symbols
\newcommand{\cardsep}{\hspace*{0.2em}}

%defines a vertical bridge hand with seat name
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\hand}{smm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \blackened_hand_horizontal:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
   {
    \blackened_hand:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_blackened_hand_seq
\clist_new:N \l_blackened_suit_clist

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_hand_horizontal:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_blackened_hand_seq { ; } { #2 }
  \mbox{\mnspade   \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 1 } }\quad
  \mbox{\mnheart   \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 2 } }\quad
  \mbox{\mndiamond \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 3 } }\quad
  \mbox{\mnclub    \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 4 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_hand:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_blackened_hand_seq { ; } { #2 }
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
  \begin{tabbing}
 \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 } { \textbf{#1} \\ }
  \mnspade   \= \cardsep \= \blackened_set_suit:n { 1 } \\
  \mnheart   \>          \> \blackened_set_suit:n { 2 } \\
  \mndiamond \>          \> \blackened_set_suit:n { 3 } \\
  \mnclub    \>          \> \blackened_set_suit:n { 4 }
  \end{tabbing}
  \end{minipage}
 }

\tl_const:Nn \c_blackened_ten_tl { 10 }
\tl_new:N \l_blackened_suit_tl
\seq_new:N \l_blackened_suit_seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_set_suit:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_blackened_suit_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_blackened_hand_seq { #1 } }
  \tl_if_blank:VTF \l_blackened_suit_tl
   { --- } % no card in the suit
   {
    \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l_blackened_suit_tl { 10 } { \c_blackened_ten_tl }
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l_blackened_suit_seq { } \l_blackened_suit_tl
    \seq_use:Nn \l_blackened_suit_seq { \cardsep }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%********************************************************************************


%********************************************************************************
% BRIDGE DIAGRAM

\newcommand{\bd}[4]{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{ p{7em} p{7em} p{7em}}
 & #1 & \\
#2 & {\vspace{4pt}\begin{tikzpicture} \draw (0,0) rectangle (1.3,1.3); \end{tikzpicture}} & #3\\
   & #4 &
\end{tabular}
}
%********************************************************************************


%********************************************************************************
% custom minipage (needed for spacial cases)

\newlength{\myminipageparskip}
\newenvironment{bdminipage}
  {\setlength{\myminipageparskip}{1ex}% save the value
   \begin{minipage}{21em}% open the minipage
   \setlength{\parskip}{\myminipageparskip}% restore the value
  }
  {\end{minipage}}
%********************************************************************************


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{bdminipage}
\bd
{\hand{North}{QJ42; 7; AJ763; 843}}%
{\hand{West}{K1085; AK543; Q4; AJ}}%
{\hand{East}{976; Q862; K10952; K}}%
{\hand{South}{A3; J109; 8; Q1097652}}%
\end{bdminipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

How can modify the macro so that I can produce diagrams like:

[image]

The example has only two suits, but it could have been one, the suit symbols might have been different, I might wish not to include seat names, in some extreme cases, one seat may have two suits, while other seats have only one suit, etc. So, flexibility is paramount, and infinitely appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an optional argument to `\hand` that specifies what suits you want to show; the order is unimportant, the suits are called by name: S = spades, H = hearts, D = diamonds, C = clubs.

There are slight complications for getting the alignments right, but I think I solved them.

```
    %********************************************************************************
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in,paperheight=9in, margin=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{MnSymbol} % not needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{libertine}
%********************************************************************************


%********************************************************************************
% Use MnSymbol suit symbols

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolCards}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.1] MnSymbolC5
   <6-7>  s*[1.1] MnSymbolC6
   <7-8>  s*[1.1] MnSymbolC7
   <8-9>  s*[1.1] MnSymbolC8
   <9-10> s*[1.1] MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> s*[1.1] MnSymbolC10
  <12->   s*[1.1] MnSymbolC12}{}

\newcommand{\mndiamond}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A2}}}
\newcommand{\mnheart}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A3}}}
\newcommand{\mnspade}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A4}}}
\newcommand{\mnclub}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A5}}}
%********************************************************************************


%********************************************************************************
% BRIDGE HAND
% macros to produce horizontal and vertical bridge hand

%Defines "hair space" to be used after suit symbols
\newcommand{\cardsep}{\hspace*{0.2em}}

%defines a vertical bridge hand with seat name
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\hand}{sO{S,H,D,C}mm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \blackened_hand_horizontal:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
   {
    \blackened_hand:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_blackened_hand_seq
\clist_new:N \l_blackened_suit_clist

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_hand_horizontal:nnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_blackened_hand_seq { ; } { #3 }
  \hspace*{-1em}% remove the initial \quad
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { S }
   { \quad \mbox{\mnspade   \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 1 } } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { H }
   { \quad \mbox{\mnheart   \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 2 } } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { D }
   { \quad \mbox{\mndiamond \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 3 } } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { C }
   { \quad \mbox{\mnclub    \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 4 } } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_hand:nnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_blackened_hand_seq { ; } { #3 }
  \bool_gset_false:N \g_blackened_newline_bool
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \begin{tabbing}
  \tl_if_blank:nTF { #2 }
    { \bool_gset_false:N \g_blackened_newline_bool }
    { \bool_gset_true:N \g_blackened_newline_bool \textbf{#2} }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { S }
   { \blackened_newline: \mnspade   \= \cardsep \= \blackened_set_suit:n { 1 } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { H }
   { \blackened_newline: \mnheart   \= \cardsep \= \blackened_set_suit:n { 2 } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { D }
   { \blackened_newline: \mndiamond \= \cardsep \= \blackened_set_suit:n { 3 } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { C }
   { \blackened_newline: \mnclub    \= \cardsep \= \blackened_set_suit:n { 4 } }
  \end{tabbing}
  \end{minipage}
  \bool_gset_false:N \g_blackened_newline_bool
 }

\tl_const:Nn \c_blackened_ten_tl { 10 }
\tl_new:N \l_blackened_suit_tl
\seq_new:N \l_blackened_suit_seq
\bool_new:N \g_blackened_newline_bool

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_newline:
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \g_blackened_newline_bool
   { \\ }
   { \bool_gset_true:N \g_blackened_newline_bool }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_set_suit:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_blackened_suit_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_blackened_hand_seq { #1 } }
  \tl_if_blank:VTF \l_blackened_suit_tl
   { --- } % no card in the suit
   {
    \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l_blackened_suit_tl { 10 } { \c_blackened_ten_tl }
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l_blackened_suit_seq { } \l_blackened_suit_tl
    \seq_use:Nn \l_blackened_suit_seq { \cardsep }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%********************************************************************************


%********************************************************************************
% BRIDGE DIAGRAM

\newcommand{\bd}[4]{%
\begin{tabular}{ m{7em} m{7em} m{7em}}
 & #1 & \\
#2 & \parbox{7em}{
       \vspace{1ex}
       \begin{tikzpicture} \draw (0,0) rectangle (1.3,1.3); \end{tikzpicture}
       \vspace{1ex}
     } & #3\\
   & #4 &
\end{tabular}
}
%********************************************************************************


%********************************************************************************
% custom minipage (needed for spacial cases)

\newlength{\myminipageparskip}
\newenvironment{bdminipage}
  {\setlength{\myminipageparskip}{1ex}% save the value
   \begin{minipage}{21em}% open the minipage
   \setlength{\parskip}{\myminipageparskip}% restore the value
  }
  {\end{minipage}}
%********************************************************************************


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{bdminipage}
\bd
{\hand{North}{QJ42; 7; AJ763; 843}}%
{\hand{West}{K1085; AK543; Q4; AJ}}%
{\hand{East}{976; Q862; K10952; K}}%
{\hand{South}{A3; J109; 8; Q1097652}}%
\end{bdminipage}

\bigskip

\begin{bdminipage}
\bd
{\hand[S,H]{North}{QJ42; 7; AJ763; 843}}%
{\hand[S,H]{West}{K1085; AK543; Q4; AJ}}%
{\hand[S,H]{East}{976; Q862; K10952; K}}%
{\hand[S,H]{South}{A3; J109; 8; Q1097652}}%
\end{bdminipage}

\bigskip

\begin{bdminipage}
\bd
{\hand[S]{}{QJ42; 7; AJ763; 843}}%
{\hand[H]{}{K1085; AK543; Q4; AJ}}%
{\hand[D]{}{976; Q862; K10952; K}}%
{\hand[C]{}{A3; J109; 8; Q1097652}}%
\end{bdminipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A version with colored suits.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in,paperheight=9in, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Use FdSymbol suit symbols

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{FdSymbolCards}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolCards}{m}{n}{
    <->  s*[0.9] FdSymbolA-Book
}{}
\newcommand{\fddiamondsuit}{{\usefont{U}{FdSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"B5}}}
\newcommand{\fddiamondredsuit}{\textcolor{red!90!blue}{\usefont{U}{FdSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"B6}}}
\newcommand{\fdheartsuit}{{\usefont{U}{FdSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"B7}}}
\newcommand{\fdheartredsuit}{\textcolor{red!90!blue}{\usefont{U}{FdSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"B8}}}
\newcommand{\fdspadesuit}{{\usefont{U}{FdSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"B9}}}
\newcommand{\fdclubsuit}{{\usefont{U}{FdSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"BA}}}
\newif\ifcolorsuits
\newcommand{\fddiamond}{\fddiamondsuit}
\newcommand{\fdheart}{\fdheartsuit}
\newcommand{\fdspade}{\fdspadesuit}
\newcommand{\fdclub}{\fdclubsuit}

\AtBeginDocument{\ifcolorsuits\colorsuits\fi}
\newcommand{\colorsuits}{%
    \renewcommand{\fddiamond}{\fddiamondredsuit}%
    \renewcommand{\fdheart}{\fdheartredsuit}%
}
% BRIDGE HAND
% macros to produce horizontal and vertical bridge hand

%Defines "hair space" to be used after suit symbols
\newcommand{\cardsep}{\hspace*{0.2em}}

%defines a vertical bridge hand with seat name
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\hand}{sO{S,H,D,C}mm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \blackened_hand_horizontal:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
   {
    \blackened_hand:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_blackened_hand_seq
\clist_new:N \l_blackened_suit_clist

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_hand_horizontal:nnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_blackened_hand_seq { ; } { #3 }
  \hspace*{-1em}% remove the initial \quad
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { S }
   { \quad \mbox{\fdspade   \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 1 } } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { H }
   { \quad \mbox{\fdheart   \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 2 } } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { D }
   { \quad \mbox{\fddiamond \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 3 } } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { C }
   { \quad \mbox{\fdclub    \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 4 } } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_hand:nnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_blackened_hand_seq { ; } { #3 }
  \bool_gset_false:N \g_blackened_newline_bool
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \begin{tabbing}
  \tl_if_blank:nTF { #2 }
    { \bool_gset_false:N \g_blackened_newline_bool }
    { \bool_gset_true:N \g_blackened_newline_bool \textbf{#2} }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { S }
   { \blackened_newline: \fdspade   \= \cardsep \= \blackened_set_suit:n { 1 } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { H }
   { \blackened_newline: \fdheart   \= \cardsep \= \blackened_set_suit:n { 2 } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { D }
   { \blackened_newline: \fddiamond \= \cardsep \= \blackened_set_suit:n { 3 } }
  \clist_if_in:nnT { #1 } { C }
   { \blackened_newline: \fdclub    \= \cardsep \= \blackened_set_suit:n { 4 } }
  \end{tabbing}
  \end{minipage}
  \bool_gset_false:N \g_blackened_newline_bool
 }

\tl_const:Nn \c_blackened_ten_tl { 10 }
\tl_new:N \l_blackened_suit_tl
\seq_new:N \l_blackened_suit_seq
\bool_new:N \g_blackened_newline_bool

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_newline:
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \g_blackened_newline_bool
   { \\ }
   { \bool_gset_true:N \g_blackened_newline_bool }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_set_suit:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_blackened_suit_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_blackened_hand_seq { #1 } }
  \tl_if_blank:VTF \l_blackened_suit_tl
   { --- } % no card in the suit
   {
    \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l_blackened_suit_tl { 10 } { \c_blackened_ten_tl }
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l_blackened_suit_seq { } \l_blackened_suit_tl
    \seq_use:Nn \l_blackened_suit_seq { \cardsep }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%********************************************************************************


%********************************************************************************
% BRIDGE DIAGRAM

\newcommand{\bd}[4]{%
\begin{tabular}{ m{7em} m{7em} m{7em}}
 & #1 & \\
#2 & \parbox{7em}{
       \vspace{1ex}
       \begin{tikzpicture} \draw (0,0) rectangle (1.3,1.3); \end{tikzpicture}
       \vspace{1ex}
     } & #3\\
   & #4 &
\end{tabular}
}
%********************************************************************************


%********************************************************************************
% custom minipage (needed for spacial cases)

\newlength{\myminipageparskip}
\newenvironment{bdminipage}
  {\setlength{\myminipageparskip}{1ex}% save the value
   \begin{minipage}{21em}% open the minipage
   \setlength{\parskip}{\myminipageparskip}% restore the value
  }
  {\end{minipage}}
%********************************************************************************

\colorsuitstrue

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{bdminipage}
\bd
{\hand{North}{QJ42; 7; AJ763; 843}}%
{\hand{West}{K1085; AK543; Q4; AJ}}%
{\hand{East}{976; Q862; K10952; K}}%
{\hand{South}{A3; J109; 8; Q1097652}}%
\end{bdminipage}

\bigskip

\begin{bdminipage}
\bd
{\hand[S,H]{North}{QJ42; 7; AJ763; 843}}%
{\hand[S,H]{West}{K1085; AK543; Q4; AJ}}%
{\hand[S,H]{East}{976; Q862; K10952; K}}%
{\hand[S,H]{South}{A3; J109; 8; Q1097652}}%
\end{bdminipage}

\bigskip

\begin{bdminipage}
\bd
{\hand[S]{}{QJ42; 7; AJ763; 843}}%
{\hand[H]{}{K1085; AK543; Q4; AJ}}%
{\hand[D]{}{976; Q862; K10952; K}}%
{\hand[C]{}{A3; J109; 8; Q1097652}}%
\end{bdminipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

By default, the red suits are printed hollow, but with `\colorsuitstrue` in the preamble or after `\colorsuits` in the document, they appear in red.

[image]

Comment: @blackened Now it should be OK

Comment: @blackened This code uses the same font as the document.

Comment: @blackened Yes, of course there is. Add `\sffamily` after `\begin{tabbing}`

Comment: @blackened That's well known: if you use it in text just use `2+\mnspade\ and`

Comment: Sorry for bugging you often. When I use suit symbols in book sections (\mndiamond, etc.), I get `Missing number, treated as zero` error. But the section name, etc. is still output correctly. Is this normal?

Comment: @blackened `\protect\mndiamond`; or use `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand` for the relevant macros you're going to use in titles.

Comment: Hello egreg! Is it possible to have a switch to make the heart and diamond symbol in color (say, red) and not hollow?

Comment: @blackened added

Comment: Thank you very much. You are very kind.